# Is there an in-built operation that will binarise a grayscale Bitmap with respect to an intensity threshold?

Tags: .net-4.0

Is there an in-built operation that will binarise a grayscale Bitmap with respect to an intensity threshold?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing built in, you will have to write your own.